# YouTube Data API not returning correct videos for language query using relevanceLanguage=en

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am having issues while making queries to the YouTube Data API, I ask for videos that are in English, but other language videos are also returned in the API response.

Example query:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&key=MYKEY&maxResults=50&relevanceLanguage=en&q=bitcoing

Example non-English video from the response:

```
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "w8XrPbjZTYYjwhjqjl4HLLlFg5o",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "p8dzJSJZ7EE"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2013-12-02T19:44:07Z",
        "channelId": "UCFOSg71CRAJ58IPuV_-jMbw",
        "title": "¿Qué es Bitcoin? Y las monedas virtuales (en Español)",
        "description": "Todo sobre Bitcoin (funcionamiento, minería, ventajas, desventajas...) y las monedas digitales como Litecoin, Freicoin y Ripple. ¡SUSCRIBETE y apoya nuestro ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p8dzJSJZ7EE/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p8dzJSJZ7EE/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/p8dzJSJZ7EE/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Tecnonauta",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2013-12-02T19:44:07Z"
      }
    },
```

Any tips on this are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: relevance does not mean always or only.    relevance means relevant to the request only google would know what qualified as relevant to the request.   That suggests this is working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official docs, the parameter [`relevanceLanguage`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relevanceLanguage) of the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint has the following specification (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**relevanceLanguage**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#relevanceLanguage) (string)
>
> The `relevanceLanguage` parameter instructs the API to return search results that are most relevant to the specified language. The parameter value is typically an [ISO 639-1 two-letter language code](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). However, you should use the values `zh-Hans` for simplified Chinese and `zh-Hant` for traditional Chinese. *Please note that results in other languages will still be returned if they are highly relevant to the search query term.*

Consequently, when invoked with `relevanceLanguage=en`, the `Search.list` endpoint *is not required to return videos that are only in English language*.

Comment: Thank you for your highlights.